# vba XMLHTTP60 get webpage title and some regex from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, vba, web-scraping

from what I always use:

```
Url$ = "www.somewebpage.com"
Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, worldData As Object, S$
With Http
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .send
    S = .responseText
End With
```

1. im looking for a way to **scrape** the webpage
2. looking for a way **scrape** arrays of data (shown bellow) from a webpage from a javascript (please note that this javascript doest not realy have to be there at all) of first node and then coords of first values inside the node... example of what do I expect to return bellow. How would I start:

   With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   .Pattern = "?????"
   Set worldData = .Execute(S)
   If worldData.Count > 0 Then
   'here to loop and create/assing into arrays
   End If
   End With

data on the webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var g_mapperData = { 
        40: { 
            '0': { 
                count: 3,
                coords: [
                    [45.2,69.9,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}],
                    [45.5,69.5,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}],
                    [44.8,68,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}]
                ]
            }  
        },    
        12: { 
            '0': { 
                count: 1,
                coords: [
                    [48.4,86.61,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}]
                ]
            }  
        },    
        3524: { 
            '0': { 
                count: 2,
                coords: [
                    [48.2,70.9,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}],
                    [46.1,70.7,{label:'$2$1<br><div class=q0><small>Respawn: 2min</small><br><small>Phase: 1</small><br>$3</div>',type: '0'}]
                ]
            }  
        }   
    };
</script>
```

expected result of arrays:

```
MapID = {40, 12, 3524}
Xcoord = {45.2, 48.4, 48.2}
Ycoord = {69.9, 86.61, 70.9}
```

each of the array always should have same lenght of values, as in every "MapID" is at least one record of X/Y (could be more, up to hundreds even), and also MapIDs could be just one or even hundreds.

Thank you wizards for magic

Comment: "please note that this javascript doest not really have to be there at all" - this is pretty confusing - if you're not scraping that, then where would you be getting the data from?

Comment: @TimWilliams: saying that javascript doesnt have to be then, then nothing will be scrapped and those 3 arrays will be empty. So we can use if "g_mapperData" exists

Comment: @QHarr: i dont do python :( I can go only for VBA as far as im saving data into excel. the RegEx is also my thought, but this could be done via VBA, right?

Comment: Do you only ever take the first record in the coords collections for each MapId? For example, do you ignore 45.5,69.5 for keyId "40" ? If not, how should these additional records be represented in output?

Comment: @QHarr yes only first record, others should be omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure and the keys are regular then you could use regex to grab the parent `g_mapper_Data` var and parse with `jsonconverter.bas`; being sure to set the unquoted keys flag to `True`. Here I am reading the `.responseText` from cell A1. You would want to develop the error handling in particular. This is a little rough and ready and there are a lot of assumptions made.

N.B.

In VBA JSON {} is a dictionary that you can loop the keys of or access by key; [] indicates a collection you can For Each over. The json is nested. You will need to familiarize yourself with these concepts.

For json parsing I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). Download raw code from there and add to standard module called JsonConverter. You then need to go `VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code (this is for if you import the .bas direct).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfoFromScriptTag()
    'required reference Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions; Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim s As String, re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    s = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    re.Pattern = "g_mapperData = (\{[\s\S]+?\});"

    Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, json As Object

    Set matches = re.Execute(s)

    If matches.Count Then

        JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True

        On Error GoTo errhand

        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(matches.item(0).SubMatches(0))

        Dim key As Variant, dict As Scripting.Dictionary

        Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary      'to be a dict of collections

        For Each key In json.keys()
            dict.Add key, json(key)("0")("coords")(1) 'assumes unique keys
        Next

        'MapID = {40, 12, 3524}, Xcoord = {45.2, 48.4, 48.2}, Ycoord = {69.9, 86.61, 70.9}

        Dim mapId(), xCoord(), yCoord(), i As Long

        mapId = dict.keys

        ReDim xCoord(0 To UBound(mapId))
        ReDim yCoord(0 To UBound(mapId))

        For Each key In dict
            xCoord(i) = dict(key)(1)
            yCoord(i) = dict(key)(2)
            i = i + 1
        Next
        Stop
    End If
    Exit Sub
errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub
```

---

Output:

[image]

---

Regex:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

thanks, it works very fine...
I have slightly adjusted to work for my purposes:

```
Sub test()

Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, s As String, re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, json As Object
Dim key As Variant, dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim mapId(), xCoord(), yCoord(), i As Long
Dim mapId_element As Variant

For row = 2 To 2 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-Scrap").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-Scrap").Cells(row, 2)) Then

        'World Data
        Url$ = "www.somewebpage.com/?item=" & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value2
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .send
            s = .responseText
        End With
        With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            .Pattern = "g_mapperData = (\{[\s\S]+?\});"
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            If matches.Count > 0 Then

                JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True

                On Error GoTo errhand

                Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(matches.Item(0).SubMatches(0))
                Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary      'to be a dict of collections

                For Each key In json.Keys()
                    dict.Add key, json(key)("0")("coords")(1) 'assumes unique keys
                Next

                'MapID = {40, 12, 3524}, Xcoord = {45.2, 48.4, 48.2}, Ycoord = {69.9, 86.61, 70.9}

                mapId = dict.Keys

                ReDim xCoord(0 To UBound(mapId))
                ReDim yCoord(0 To UBound(mapId))

                For Each key In dict
                    xCoord(i) = dict(key)(1)
                    yCoord(i) = dict(key)(2)
                    i = i + 1
                Next
                'Stop
            End If
        End With

    End If

    'Clear for next loop
    Set matches = Nothing
    Set json = Nothing
    Set dict = Nothing
    Erase mapId
    Erase xCoord
    Erase yCoord
    i = Empty

errhand:
If Err.Number > 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

Next row

End Sub
```

so I have just one additional question.
From initial post, what would be "simple" for this script to also collect  value?
The way i know how is definitely not easy, and would slow quite a lot...

Comment: You don't need to keep creating the regex object. Create it once outside the loop and place it in  variable and set the pattern and flag there.  Inside the loop simply use With regex : Set matches = ........